Is it permissible to make contributions to a SEP-IRA in excess of the current year's maximum and allocate them to the following year?
Is it permissible to make contributions to a SEP-IRA in excess of the current tax year's maximum allowed amount if those excess contributions are allocated to the following tax year?

Generally no. You'd probably want to talk to a professional. The IRS does describe a corrective action that allows retaining the amounts, but that would include some additional penalty (10% of the excess contribution) to be paid and forms submitted to the IRS. See here:

There are two alternative methods to correct a failure to limit employer contributions to employees.
The amount in excess of the annual limit, adjusted for earnings through the date of correction, should be distributed from the affected employee’s SEP-IRA and returned to the employer. The distributed amount is not included in the income of the affected employee, but is reported on Form 1099-R with a taxable amount of zero. If it isn’t feasible to determine what the actual investment results would’ve been, you may use a reasonable rate of interest, such as the interest rate used by the Department of Labor’s Voluntary Fiduciary Correction Program Online Calculator.
Alternatively, if a submission is made under the VCP program, the excess amount may be retained in the SEP-IRA, but only if the plan agrees to enter into a closing agreement and pay an additional amount to the IRS via an imposed sanction that is equal to at least 10% of the excess amount, excluding earnings. Note that the additional compliance fee will not apply if the excess amount is under $100.
Under both correction methods, the plan sponsor is not entitled to a deduction for the excess contributions.


Does anything change if it's a sole-proprietorship with a single person (no employees, such as a consultant) who deposits the funds into his own retirement account?

@Tim no, nothing changes.
